# Поиск по всему JSON файлу

Tags: c#, json.net

Есть небольшой `JSON` файл (~400 строк), который имеет подобную структуру:

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "type": "Тип 1",
      "Ключ1": "Значение 1",
      "Ключ2": "Значение 2"
    },
    {
      "type": "Тип 2",
      "Ключ3": "Значение 3",
      "Ключ4": "Значение 4"
    }
  ]
}
```

Файл как видно разбит по разделам, где первое значение всегда `type` - данное значение указывает название категории. Также в каждой категории имеется значение (тут я обозначил как ключ) - оно уникально.

Вопрос, как мне совершить поиск по **всему** файлу имея только `Ключ` - получить его `Значение` и текущую "категорию", которая находится в `type`?

На данный момент я загружаю весь файл построчно и в получившемся массиве ищю строку, которая имеет нужный ключ. Далее я это значение десериализирую и вытаскиваю значение. Такой вариант работает довольно хорошо, но я не могу получить `type`, да и сам этот вариант выглядит как "костыль".

---

Для большей понятности пример:

Имеем к примеру "Ключ3" - делаем поиск - на выходе получаем "Значение 3" и "Тип 2".

Comment: Нужно создать класс и десериализировать json  в List. Там уже можно с помощью Linq или простым перебором найти нужные строки.

Comment: Поддерживаю предыдущего оратора. JSON — формат _сериализации_ данных. Десериализуйте и ищите в объектной структуре то, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С учетом вашей структуры `JSON`  данных и при нежелании десериализовать в объектный вид, вашу задачу можно решить так, благо фреймворк `Json.Net` поддерживает `Linq`:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
var result = json["Items"]
    .Where(s => s["Ключ3"] != null)
    .Select(s => new
     {
         Value = s["Ключ3"].ToString(),
         Type = s["type"]?.ToString()
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: _Первый_ знак вопроса можно по идее убрать, вы ж проверяете, что `s["Ключ3"] != null`.

Comment: @VladD спасибо, верное замечание.

Comment: @sp7 Спасибо, хорошее решение.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, пожалуйста.